# Help with understanding this example of Dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis

$$A\mid B = \{r \in \mathbb{Q} \mid  r \le 0, r^2 < 2 \} \mid  \{r \in \mathbb{Q} \mid r>0, r^2 \ge 2 \}$$

I have trouble understanding this; can't we just remove $r \le 0$ from $A$ and also remove $r>0$ from $B$ to say that $A$ refers to all rational numbers in between $- \sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$ and $B$ refers to everything else?

Thank you.

Comment: The $A$ you write in set notation is not equal to all rationals between $-\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}$. It is the set of all rationals between $-\sqrt{2}$ and $0$. Similarly, $B$ contains only positive rationals that are greater than $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Yes, conjunctions are important! You need an "or" in the expression for $A$ and an "and" in the expression for $B$.

Answer (score 1):

You could. But then $B$ would contain $-2$ and $A$ would contain $0$, which violates the property that everything in $B$ should be larger than everything in $A$.